# How to create unic ArrayList in Java on other indexes with a group of numbers

Tags: java, arraylist, numbers

See my code below; I need of 6 single group of numbers without repetition.

I need a `for` statement to generate 6 unique numbers, I need without entire repetition on next indexes

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n = 15;
    ArrayList<Integer> Numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
    ArrayList SingleGroup = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList Groups = new ArrayList();
    Random rand = new Random();
    rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    while (Numbers.size() < 15) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Integer r = rand.nextInt(60);
            if (r != 0) {
                if (!Numbers.contains(r)) {
                    if (Numbers.size() < 15) {
                        Numbers.add(r);
                        Collections.sort(Numbers);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to list only 6 numbers, and then group in an arraylist, then that putting a new arraylist grouping in each index each new group of numbers drawn.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {        
            while ((Groups.size() < 6)&& (SingleGroup.size() < 6)) {
                Integer val = rand.nextInt(14);
                if (!SingleGroup.contains(Numbers.get(val))) {
                    SingleGroup.add(Numbers.get(val));
                }
                if (SingleGroup.size() == 6) {
                    Groups.add(i, SingleGroup);
                    //SingleGroup.set(0, 7);
                }                   
                Collections.sort(SingleGroup);
            }
        }
    System.out.println(Numbers);
    System.out.println(Groups);
}
```

How to create unic ArrayList in Java on other indexes with a group of numbers

Comment: You are using *raw* `ArrayList`. Don't!!!

Comment: Unclear what you want. Please edit question, clean up the text, and show example of what you want.

Comment: run:
[4, 6, 10, 14, 17, 20, 32, 39, 40, 41, 45, 49, 52, 55, 59]
[[6, 20, 32, 45, 49, 52]] ,-- Here is only single one output
Done with sucess, but i need six (6) output in others numbers listed in group but a new index not only 0 index

Comment: Why are you sorting Numbers?  and why every time you add a new element??? Seems to me you could simply [shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) your Numbers array, and then take a [subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) of the first 6 elements and create a new ArrayList from that.

Comment: "unic" = unique?

Comment: @Aueiorl Which part of *"edit question"* did you not understand? Don't clarify in a comment, **edit the question** and clarify it.

Comment: So you want code to get 15 unique random numbers between 0 and 59 (inclusive), then repeatedly (6 times) grab 6 of those 15 numbers? So you end up with 6 groups of 6 numbers, all numbers are from original 15 unique numbers, and a number may be in more than one group, but only once per group? Did I get that right?

Comment: @Andreas And, each group is sorted, if I’m reading the original code correctly.

Comment: yes unique @markspace

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the requirements correctly, the following Java 8 code will do what you want. It relies on [`shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) and [`subList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) to get 6 random numbers of a list of 15.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new Random().ints(0, 60).distinct().limit(15)
                        .sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(numbers);

List<List<Integer>> groups = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    ArrayList<Integer> group = new ArrayList<>(numbers.subList(0, 6));
    Collections.sort(group);
    groups.add(group);
}
System.out.println(groups);
```

*Sample Output*

```
[14, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 26, 28, 31, 39, 41, 42, 43, 45]
[[21, 23, 28, 39, 41, 43], [20, 23, 31, 39, 41, 43], [14, 17, 31, 39, 41, 43], [21, 23, 25, 26, 41, 43], [19, 20, 21, 31, 43, 45], [19, 21, 23, 28, 39, 42]]
```

Comment: Why not `groups.add(numbers.stream().limit(6).sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));`?

Comment: Very nice job mate, thank you, this works fine, you are like a boss!

Comment: @Andreas you know how stream.Collectors works on android studio

Comment: @AJNeufeld Because I'm an old dog, weary of new tricks, who prefers "regular" code to those newfangled streams. Most of the time, anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient implementation of what it is that we think you want, but with only 15 elements in the `Numbers` list, the inefficiency is negligible.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> Groups = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Collections.shuffle(Numbers);
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>( Numbers.subList(0, 6) );
    Collections.sort(temp);
    Groups.add(temp);
}
```

Finally, sort `Numbers`, if desired.